# Print Search Query

Tags: php, html, search

index.html code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" name="search">
    <input type="text" id="search_query" class="field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search a website ..."/>&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>
```

search.php code:

```
<input type="text" id="go" class="field" name="go" value=""/>&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>
```

I want to prefill the search.php  search box from the searched text on the index.html page

One more thing, I want to do something so people can't click the search button if there is the Search a website... value

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" name="search"> 
    <input type="search" id="search_query" class="field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search a website ..."/>&nbsp; 
    <input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: Did you mean to pre filled  the value of input with  type="text" id="go"  from index page ti search page

Comment: Are u using PDO or mysqli to connect to ur DB to query the result of the text entered by the user

Comment: Im using mysqli Falt4rm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're dealing with search engines it's best to use GET method instead of using POST because you are getting data, so use GET in your search form.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" name="search">
<input type="text" id="search_query" class="field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search a website ..."/>&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>

<input type="text" id="go" class="field" name="go" value=""/>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['search_query']))
              echo $_GET['search_query'] ?>
<input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>
```

and that's all just an opinion.

Comment: One more thing, I want to do something so people can't click the search button if there is the Search a website... value    <form action="search.php" method="get" name="search">
            <input type="search" id="search_query" class="field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search a website ..."/>&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>

Answer (score 0):

If u understood correctly the question u want to pre filled the value of input with type="text" from index page to search page.

That should do it - 
search.php code :

```
<input type="text" id="go" class="field" name="go" value=""/>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['search_query']))
              echo $_POST['search_query'] ?>
<input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Search"/>
```